# MySql Syntax Error From AutoGenerated Creation

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE  `db`.`Complete` (

`CompleteId` MEDIUMINT( 8 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`HoursTaken` DOUBLE( 5 ) NOT NULL ,
`DateFinished` DATETIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

I am trying to create this **simple** table, however, I get an error. The above code is the code *generated* by a UI for a MySql database.

I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL ,
`DateFinished` DATETIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM' at line 4
```

I am not sure what to change.

Comment: mysql has no ui. What exactly did you use to dump out that create statement? `show create table ...` would not put spaces around the field size portions. e.g. it'd generate `mediumint(8)`, not `mediumint( 8 )`.

Comment: @Marc B - It could be MySQL Workbench or PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: @MarcB - This is a Starfield Technologies generated script. MySql has no default UI that is true, but that doesn't mean there doesn't exist UI's for it. Surely that is not what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the precision to the `DOUBLE` datatype, it should be `DOUBLE(5,n)` I think.

Comment: This could be the case, the issue was definitely with the DOUBLE definition. I solved the problem by using a float instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using float instead of double, this was the generated code:

```
CREATE TABLE  `db`.`Complete` (
`CompleteId` MEDIUMINT( 8 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`HoursTaken` FLOAT NOT NULL ,
`DateFinished` DATETIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```